# Finding the exp

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Hi I have a question on the result of the following function
The input is the row vector of x and we are outputing the calculated exp value using the `∑_(n=0)^(n=50)▒(x^n)/n!` (i.e. Summation from n=0 to n=50 using `x^n)/n!`)
The loop will terminate either when n reaches 50 or `(x^n)/n!` < 0.01

```
function [summ] = ExpFunction(x)
```

// there is a loop to iterate.

There are two versions
1) We write an if to see if the value `(x^n)/n!` is >= 0.01. if it is then add it the the summ.
2) Add it to the summ first and then check if `(x^n)/n!` is >= 0.01. if not then terminates the program.

My question is that why do the two versions produce different results and the second version appears to produce better results(i.e. closer the exp(x) )

Thank you

version 1:

```
function [result] = Exp(x)
result = 0;
a = 0;
n = 0;
while(n <= 50)
{
    a = (x.^n)/factorial(n)  %% The factorial function is self written have have been checked.
    if(abs(a) >= 0.01)
        result = result + a;
    else
        break;
    n = n + 1;
}
```

Second version is to do result = result + a; before checking abs(a) >=0.01

Comment: Versions 1 and 2 appear to be doing different things.  Version 2 adds one extra term where `(x^n)/n! < 0.01` whereas Version 1 does not.  Can you check your logic again?

Comment: But version 2 would have the risk to have added the one that is less then 0.01. For example, for x = 2, at n = 8 it's less than 0.01. Using version 1: we would have avoided the summation

Comment: Post all of your code, thanks.  Your question is misleading

Comment: I got it now. It's just a litle problem in the quesition. The question wants the (x^n)/n! to be greater than 0.01. But in reality, exp is taken to the infinity. Hence the second version will yield a more accurate result. Thank you sooo much Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems simple. The series is increasing (i.e. each addition results in a larger sum) and the limit value is being approached from below. This means that every new term added to the sum is getting closer to the final value = the limit. This results in each addition being a better approximation to the result.
It is also clear that the first method, not adding the term, will result in a slightly less accurate result than the second method, which does add the term.

It is clear that the accuracy of the result is improved by adding more terms. The only cost is the extra computing time. Is your termination criterion (x^n/factorial(n) < 0.01) giving good enough values for all values of x? I would have expected you to use a formula more like (x^n/factorial(n) < g(x)) where g(x) is a formula involving x. I suggest that you go back to the text on series and determine whether a better g(x) is required for your accuracy requirements.